# Javascript - Object.create: Is my understanding correct?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal

I am trying to understand fully how prototypes work.

This is my definition of a prototype:

> A built in property that all objects have (except the Base Object) which points to and references a 'proto{}' object which is a copy of another object whose properties and methods can then be referenced if not found in the original object.

Is that correct? Especially I'm wondering about the 'is a copy of another object' part - meaning that the JS Engine creates a stored copy of Object B in memory space which the prototype property of Object A points to for reference.

Now my questions about `Object.create`:

My understanding is that this method makes the prototype (or the object itself?) of whatever object it is used on, inherit (IOW, reference a copy of the passed in Object) the properties and methods of another object that is passed in.

```
var john = Object.create(Person);
```

In the above code, the `john` object is created and it's 
    prototype property points to a created object that has the methods and 
    properties of the `Person` object? Or to put it differently, `Object.create` makes a copy of the `Person` object and puts it in a memory space that the prototype property of `john` points to.  Is this a correct understanding of what's going on?

If so, is the reason that a copy of the object ('person') is made, that the prototype of `john` points to, because that allows the values of the properties and methods to be modified without overwriting the props/methods in the `Person` object that the prototype object associated with `john` inherited?

I am trying to break this down so I can understand and trying not to over-complicate the concept.

Here is a picture I drew to further illustrate my current understanding:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no copying of anything involved. Just strike that part:

> Prototype: A built in property that all objects have <s>(except the Base Object)</s> which points to and references <s>a 'proto{}' object which is a copy of</s> another object whose properties and methods can then be referenced if not found in the original object.

Keep it simple.

And yes, because there is a direct reference and nothing else involved, this means that any changes to the inherited properties of the prototype object will *dynamically* reflect in the object.

Comment: Ok, I get it now.  Thank you!